# Gamefication non-game Android app

Tags: android, google-play-services

I created an Android application (non-game) that already is alpha Test and now would like to leave it more attractive using the concept of Gamefication. Of course not want to start the implementation of the concept of zero, and would like to get the community some insight on the subject. So there's a few questions.

1) It is possible Gamefy an Android application non-game using Google Play Game API? This does not violate any rules of Google?

2) There are API's better than Google Play Game API for this purpose that non-game apps Android famous make use you recommend, or is it better to use Google Play Game API?

3) This question is specifically about Google Play Game API. As I said, currently my Android app is in Alpha Test, and his first screen is a Login / Registration screen. In this screen there are two buttons, one to log in via facebook and others via Google sign-in, where both are working perfectly. Assuming I use the Google Play Game API to Gamefy my application, it seems to me that the flow of login Google Play Game API is independent of the Google sign-in, which means you have to use only login via Google Play Game API, right?! If so, this would not be a problem since I also have the option to login via facebook? Another problem that worries me is that now I can return the User email it and some basic data either through the Google sign-in as facebook (user email is necessary, since sending this email to the server to create your account and session to keep the user logged in the app). Get email to log in with a User via Google Play Game API is possible and legal?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve out of the gamefication? Are you trying to use features like leaderboards, achievements, quests?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the Google documentation that states you cannot use the game API for a non-game app. As long as you follow all their guidelines I think it should be ok. The Google sign-in and Play sign-in are related, they are not independent. There shouldn't be a problem is you also have Facebook support.